# How to fix buggy CSS hover

Tags: html, css, debugging, hover

I am coding a page to select different products. each 'bild box' in my HTML is supposed to display a product and when you hover with you mouse over it, it zooms into the picture and a few other styling effects happen. When hovering over the boxes you can see, that randomly the boxes zoom and it looks glitchy. Here is a demonstration of the effect: https://streamable.com/wei69

I have tried to specify the different hover boxes which makes the code unnecessarily long and didn't fix the problem. Before I did this there were no classes like 'title1, title2' it was only 'title'. 
I also tried different browsers and in Safari the effect isn't that bad but it is still not user friendly.
Here is my code:

```css
#flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.bildbox1,
.bildbox2,
.bildbox3,
.bildbox4,
.bildbox5,
.bildbox6 {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.bild1,
.bild2,
.bild3,
.bild4,
.bild5 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  /* fallback color */
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
}

.bild1 {
  background-image: url("//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/3252/2611/files/selfie-413162_960_720_large.jpg?v=1549398130");
}

.bild2 {
  background-image: url("//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/3252/2611/files/selfie-413162_960_720_large.jpg?v=1549398130");
}

.bild3 {
  background-image: url("//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/3252/2611/files/selfie-413162_960_720_large.jpg?v=1549398130");
}

.bild4 {
  background-image: url("//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/3252/2611/files/selfie-413162_960_720_large.jpg?v=1549398130");
}

.bild5 {
  background-image: url("//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/3252/2611/files/selfie-413162_960_720_large.jpg?v=1549398130");
}

.textbox {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

.textbox p {
  color: darkgrey;
}

.point1,
.point2,
.point3,
.point4,
.point5 {
  width: 75px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: width .3s ease;
  -o-transition: width .3s ease;
  transition: width .3s ease;
  display: none;
}

.konfigurieren-button1,
.konfigurieren-button2,
.konfigurieren-button3,
.konfigurieren-button4,
.konfigurieren-button5 {
  background: #E30D27;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  @include inline-flexbox();
  @include align-items(center);
  @include justify-content(center);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.title1,
.title2,
.title3,
.title4,
.title5 {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 25%;
}

.konfigurieren-button1:hover,
.konfigurieren-button2:hover,
.konfigurieren-button3:hover,
.konfigurieren-button4:hover,
.konfigurieren-button5:hover,
{
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  .bildbox1:hover .bild1,
  .bildbox1:focus .bild1 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  .bildbox2:hover .bild2,
  .bildbox2:focus .bild2 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  .bildbox3:hover .bild3,
  .bildbox3:focus .bild3 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  .bildbox4:hover .bild4,
  .bildbox4:focus .bild4 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  .bildbox5:hover .bild5,
  .bildbox5:focus .bild5 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  .bildbox1:hover .title1,
  .bildbox2:hover .title2,
  .bildbox3:hover .title3,
  .bildbox4:hover .title4,
  .bildbox5:hover .title5 {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 1.0;
    color: white;
    padding: 25%;
  }
  .point1,
  .point2,
  .point3,
  .point4,
  .point5 {
    width: 0px;
    display: initial;
    top: 17%;
  }
  .title1,
  .title2,
  .title3,
  .title4,
  .title5 {
    opacity: 0.0;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    top: 0;
  }
  .konfigurieren-button1,
  .konfigurieren-button2,
  .konfigurieren-button3,
  .konfigurieren-button4,
  .konfigurieren-button5 {
    opacity: 0.0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    margin-top: 135px;
  }
  .bildbox1:hover .konfigurieren-button1,
  .bildbox2:hover .konfigurieren-button2,
  .bildbox3:hover .konfigurieren-button3,
  .bildbox4:hover .konfigurieren-button4,
  .bildbox5:hover .konfigurieren-button5 {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  .bildbox1:hover .point1,
  .bildbox2:hover .point2,
  .bildbox3:hover .point3,
  .bildbox4:hover .point4,
  .bildbox5:hover .point5 {
    width: 75px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .bildbox1,
  .bildbox2,
  .bildbox3,
  .bildbox4,
  .bildbox5,
  .bildbox6 {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div class="bildbox1">
    <div class="bild1">
      <span class="title1"> Text 1</span>
      <a href="">
        <button class="konfigurieren-button1"> Button 1</button>
      </a>
      <div class="point1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bildbox2">
    <div class="bild2">
      <span class="title2"> Text 2</span>
      <button class="konfigurieren-button2">Button 2</button>
      <div class="point2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bildbox3">
    <div class="bild3">
      <span class="title3">Text 3</span>
      <button class="konfigurieren-button3">Button 3</button>
      <div class="point3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bildbox4">
    <div class="bild4">
      <span class="title4"> Text 4</span>
      <button class="konfigurieren-button4">Button 4</button>
      <div class="point4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bildbox5">
    <div class="bild5">
      <span class="title5"> Text 5</span>
      <button class="konfigurieren-button5">Button 5</button>
      <div class="point5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bildbox6">
    <div class="textbox">
      <h3> header </h3>
      <p> paragraph
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add your all code. because mixins is undefined.

Comment: Do you only want the transform to occur on .bildboxN .bildN (where n is the number of the div) or do you want it on .bildboxN?

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;` to you `.bildbox` classes.

```
  .bildbox1,
  .bildbox2,
  .bildbox3,
  .bildbox4,
  .bildbox5,
  .bildbox6 {
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative; /* <-- Add this here */
  }
```

You have `position: absolute;` elements (your `.point` classes) that are all over the place. They need to be contained in the "boxes". When you are hovering, those position absolute elements are outside the box and overlapping other boxes.

Remember when using position absolute, that element with position itself of the first parent with a position other than static, else it will be the document window.

On a side note, is there a reason you are using classes like ids? Why do you have `.bildbox1`, `.bildbox2`, etc when you should just have 1 `.bildbox` class.

Comment: Thank you so much @zgood! I tried to find this bug for HOURS. I have another question for you: On mobile, the website has a small margin on the right. [link](https://imgur.com/a/6c1jqz2) I tried fixing this by adding 'width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);' but there is still a little margin. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Merlin don't use vw unit as they will include the scrollbar width .. simply use 100%

Comment: @TemaniAfif The Problem is, that I use this on a shopify website where the container that contains my HTML is not full width so width: 100% isn't actually 100%

Comment: @Merlin then simply add `overflow:hidden` to where you have the scroll to hide that  margin instead of removing it

Comment: @TemaniAfif what do you mean with "where you have to scroll"? (I am sorry, I am a beginner)

Comment: @Merlin I meant the element that is having the scroll due to that margin,

Comment: @zgood Yes, there Is a reason I used the classes like ids. When trying to solve this problem, I thought that my the different boxes would interfere because they had the same id. Now, that I know this is wrong, I will completely rewrite that.

Comment: @Merlin Understood, just wanted to make sure you knew the differences between ids and classes